# NDepend Discard methods for types with an attribute

Tags: .net, ndepend

How can I discard all methords (as notmycode) in types (example below) with an attribute?

For example, I have a type as:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
 public partial class OperatorSession { ... }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query for that is:

```
// <Name>Not my code, methods tagged with GeneratedCodeAttribute</Name>
notmycode from t in Application.Types
where t.HasAttribute ("System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute".AllowNoMatch())
select t
```

Notice that the [default `notmycode` query for types](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Discard_generated_Types_from_JustMyCode.html) already takes account of methods tagged with `GeneratedCodeAttribute`.

```
// <Name>Discard generated Types from JustMyCode</Name>
// --- Make sure to make this query richer to discard generated types from NDepend rules results ---
notmycode
from t in Application.Types where

  // Resources, Settings, or typed DataSet generated types for example, are tagged with this attribute
  t.HasAttribute ("System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute".AllowNoMatch()) ||

  // This attributes identifies a type or member that is not part of the user code for an application.
  t.HasAttribute ("System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute".AllowNoMatch()) ||

  // Delegate types are always generated
  t.IsDelegate ||

  // Discard ASP.NET page types generated by aspnet_compiler.exe
  // See: http://www.ndepend.com/FAQ.aspx#ASPNET
  t.ParentNamespace.Name.EqualsAny("ASP", "__ASP") ||

  // Discard generated type ContractException
  t.Name == "__ContractsRuntime+ContractException" ||
  t.FullName == "System.Diagnostics.Contracts.RuntimeContractsAttribute" ||
  t.FullName == "System.Diagnostics.Contracts.__ContractsRuntime" ||

  // Discard all types declared in a folder path containing the word "generated"
  (t.SourceFileDeclAvailable &&
   t.SourceDecls.All(s => s.SourceFile.FilePath.ParentDirectoryPath.ToString().ToLower().Contains("generated")))

select new { t, t.NbILInstructions }
```